# plotting stacked points using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, grid

I have a data frame and I would like to stack the points that have overlaps exactly on top of each other.

here is my example data:

```
value <- c(1.080251e-04, 1.708859e-01, 1.232473e-05, 4.519876e-03,2.914256e-01, 5.869711e-03, 2.196347e-01,4.124873e-01, 5.914052e-03, 2.305623e-03, 1.439013e-01, 5.407597e-03, 7.530298e-02, 7.746897e-03)
names = letters[1:7]
data <- data.frame(names = rep(names,), group = group, value = value, stringsAsFactors = T)
group <- c(rep("AA", 7) , rep("BB", 7))
```

I am using the following command:

```
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = names, y = "", color = group)) + 
geom_point(aes(size = -log(value)), position = "stack") 
plot(p)
```

But the stacked circle outlines out of the grid. I want it close or exactly next to the bottom circle. do you have any idea how I can fix the issue?

Thanks, 
[image]

Comment: Try `aes(y = 1...` and then set new y limits: `ylim(1,2)`. If this is not working, please provide a reproducible example of your dataset (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks for your response! It did not work. I have edited my question. Can you please take a look at it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The y-axis has no numeric value, so use the `group` instead. And we don't need the color legend now since the group labels are shown on the y-axis.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = names, y = group, color = group)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size = -log(value))) +
  guides(color=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thats a good idea too. Do you know how can I decrease the distance between vertical lines. I want the circles of two groups to be closer to each other.

Comment: After producing the graph, reduce the height of the device manually. Or when saving to a file, tinker with the `height` argument in the `ggsave` function. For example, `ggsave("figure1.png", height=2, width=4)`. See my edited graph.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It was really helpful. Using ggsave() reduces the hight of my figure But not as much as I want. Do you know any other way that I can play with the horizontal lines to reduce the distance between them?

Comment: You want the dots closer together, almost touching?

Comment: Maybe you can increase the size of the points: `+ scale_size_continuous(range=c(3,10))` and/or add more discrete categories to the y-axis: `+ ylim("","AA","BB","")`

Comment: I used the ylim() which is generating pretty much what I need. Thank you.